# Help, stuck with a induction proof, spivak 1.6.a

Tags: solution-verification, induction

There is this Spivak's calculus exercise:

**1.6-a** if $0\leq x < y$, then $x^n < y^n$ for $n = 1,2,3...$

he says that a proof using induction can be used, so i did the following:

$x^1 < y^1 \iff x<y$ because of the definition it is true, so this is the hypothesis:
$$ x^k < y^k\\x^{k+1}<y^{k+1}\\x^1\cdot x^k<y^1\cdot y^k$$

but then i dont know how to proceed in this, what can be done to complete the proof?

Comment: $x^k<y^k\implies x^{k+1}<x\cdot y^k<y\cdot y^k=y^{k+1}$

Comment: Well, you have these two inequalities $$\cases{x^k<y^k \\ x<y} \implies x^{k+1}< y^{k+1}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will find that problems in Spivak often use results from previous problems.

In this case, the preceding problem is relevant. Problem 1-5(viii) (3rd edition) states:

> Prove the following:
>
> If $0 \leq a < b$ and $0 \leq c < d$, then $ac < bd$.

This is what you need here.

Comment: i thought about that, but i wanted to do a complete proof without other theorems

Comment: It may be instructive to begin from Spivak's "12 basic properties of numbers" and see if you can build up to your current problem "from scratch". In general though, the problems are much more reliant on each other than you might be used to from more conventional textbooks.

Comment: As such, many problems will be difficult to tackle "a la carte". I find the book is best tackled in order, without omissions.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**:

One learns in middle school that, given an inequality $A<B$, it can be multiplied by another number $C$, using the rule
$$A<B \implies\begin{cases}AC <BC&\text{ if }C>0,\\[1ex]AC>BC&\text{ if }C<0.\end{cases}$$
You just have to apply this rule to the inductive hypothesis twice.

Comment: I'm sorry. The "middle school" comment seemed belittling, but perhaps that's not what was was intended?

Comment: I only meant that there are basic results that many people tend to forget, when they have a higher level in mathematics, as though these  results were unworthy of their level, which is an error, in my opinion. Personally I learnt many results on inequalities when I was 13  and never forgot them.

Comment: Fair enough. If you edit your answer (just to unlock it) I'll remove the downvote.

Comment: I've added a small advice on how to proceed (without to many details). B.t.w., I sometimes  use the phrasing ‘a nursery school induction’  (which comes from one og my teachers) to point out  it will be particularly easy…

Comment: Personally, I now try to avoid the widely used rhetorical math tics like, "clearly", "obviously", "it's trivial to show", and so forth, though I don't always do a good job of it. Such phrases seem to me a bit obnoxious, and likely to be discouraging to a reader whom might be struggling with the point. Everything's obvious, once you understand it. Nothing is, until then, and, as you said, the middle school stuff is just as nontrivial as the more advanced stuff.

Comment: There's a certain "arrogant IT guy" persona that comes through in some math writing. As a dumb guy that likes math despite being bad at it, I'm eager to encourage others to keep at it and not be discouraged when they get stuck, as getting stuck is absolutely part of the process.

Comment: Of course, YMMV, and I don't discount the possibility that some with enough self confidence might actually be spurred on by slightly mocking mathematics writing :)

Comment: In many problems, some parts of proofs are really standard routine, and some are tougher for beginners. In my opinion, it's more instructive to point what's non-standard and  may require tricks that not everyone has already seen.

Comment: That sounds good. I appreciate when, during some derivation, the writer can pull back and "zoom out" on the problem and paint a picture of what's really going on, point out the tricky bits, etc.

Comment: That's also my point of view. Of course, I sometimes may be too elliptic, but the O.P. always has the possibility to ask for more details or explanations.

Comment: Heh, I could stand to be more elliptic. I'm always over explaining. Probably ironically driving the reader away with my "helpful" walls of text.

Answer (score 1):

If $x^k < y^k$ is true, then multiplying both sides by $x$ leads to $x^{k+1} < x \cdot y^k$. Then apply $x < y$ to the $x$ on the right-hand side.

Comment: in the second step, why if you multiplied the initial inequality by x, you have $x\cdot y^{k+1}$?

Comment: @FavioVillaseñor Sorry, fixed my typo